# Statement Trigger PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I need to create a statement trigger that allows data to be updated in PurchaseStock table only during office hours.
The PurchaseStock table is :
**PurchaseStock (StockID, ProductID, QuantityIn, Date)**
Note that productId is a foreign key here.

I know how to create a trigger for an update but how do I cater for the hours?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, where I live, off-hours are also Saturday & Sunday (i.e. weekend), so - I'd suggest something like this:

```
SQL> create table purchase_stock (stock_id number, quantity number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_pursto
  2    before insert or update on purchase_stock
  3  declare
  4    -- day number (1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, ..., 7 = Sunday)
  5    l_day  number := to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'd'));
  6    -- current hour (e.g. now is 13:45 -> l_hour = 13)
  7    l_hour number := to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'hh24'));
  8  begin
  9    if l_day in (6, 7) or
 10       l_hour not between 9 and 17
 11    then
 12       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Non-working time; table not available');
 13    end if;
 14  end;
 15  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into purchase_stock values (1, 2);
insert into purchase_stock values (1, 2)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Non-working time; table not available
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BIU_PURSTO", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BIU_PURSTO'


SQL>
```

Comment: Understood! Thanks a lot :D
Works well!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your office hours between 08:00 and 17:00, you can create such a trigger below, to prevent updating data out of office hour you can use `raise_application_error` statement :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_upd_PrcStock
BEFORE UPDATE ON PurchaseStock 
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_hour pls_integer;    
BEGIN
  select into v_hour extract(hour from cast(sysdate as timestamp)) from dual;

  IF v_hour between 8 and 16 THEN 
   -- trigger code    
  ELSE
   raise_application_error('-20333','You can not perform update out of office hours!');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: `into hour` and the opening quote in `raise_application_error` are in the wrong place. Also I personally feel exclamation marks in error messages are poor style.

Comment: Also you could just declare `v_hour pls_integer := extract(hour from systimestamp);` and save a query of `dual`.

Comment: @William Robertson excuse me for my response in a rush. corrected now, thank you for notifications.